# Deleted remote git branch still showing up on a different clone

Tags: git

I've deleted a remote branch by running `git push origin --delete` from my local machine but when I ssh into a different machine which has a clone of the same git repository I can still see the remote branch with `git branch -av`.

Could someone please review the commands I ran and let me know if I've made a mistake or am misunderstanding something.

```
holy@my-VirtualBox:/var/www/example$  git branch -av
* master                                     6b49b28 Theme Update
  remotes/origin/BL_CustomGrid               8827318 upgraded to BL_CustomGrid

holy@my-VirtualBox:/var/www/example$ git push origin --delete BL_CustomGrid
To staging-box:/var/git/example.git
 - [deleted]         BL_CustomGrid

holy@my-VirtualBox:/var/www/example$ git branch -av
* master                1f3bb6c Theme Update
remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master 1f3bb6c Theme Update

holy@my-VirtualBox:/var/www/example$ ssh staging-box
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

   [ommiting login messages]
Last login: Tue Nov 17 14:12:36 2015 from 54.??.??.???

STAGING-box@ip-170-??-??-???:~$ cd /var/www/staging-example/
STAGING-box@ip-170-??-??-???:/var/www/staging-example$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 27, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.
From /var/git/example
   6b49b28..1f3bb6c  master     -> origin/master
Updating 6b49b28..1f3bb6c
Fast-forward
 skin/frontend/example/default/css/custom.css      | 76 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------------------
 skin/frontend/example/default/sass/_checkout.scss |  9 +++++++++
 2 files changed, 56 insertions(+), 29 deletions(-)

STAGING-box@ip-170-??-??-???:/var/www/staging-example$ git branch -av
* master                                     6b49b28 Theme Update
  remotes/origin/BL_CustomGrid               8827318 upgraded to BL_CustomGrid

STAGING-box@ip-170-??-??-???:/var/www/staging-example$ git push origin --delete BL_CustomGrid
error: unable to delete 'BL_CustomGrid': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to '/var/git/example.git'
STAGING-box@ip-170-??-??-???:/var/www/staging-example$
```

I tried [removing the git cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository/1139797#1139797) after this but it made no difference.

Comment: Don't you just need to `git pull` in changes on staging?

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx sorry, I did do that but left it of my question by mistake.  I'll update it now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your commands are right. Only thing is, that your git repository on the `STAGING-box` doesn't know that the branch is deleted. You can show such information with `git remote show origin`. You should get something like

```
[...]
BL_CustomGrid          stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
[...]
```

You need to call `remote update` with `--prune` as option to remove old tracking informations.

```
git remote update --prune
```

According to your edit: `git pull` merges changes only from the branch which are tracked from your current branch. This is showed in `git remote show origin` too:

```
[...]
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
  master                   merges with master
Local refs configured for 'git push':
  master                   pushes to master
[...]
```